# children().hasClass () not finding class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I started by posting this in a jsfiddle, but it works as expected there and not in my site, so sorry I am unable to post a fiddle that demonstrates the problem, but hopefully that info might give the clue that solves the issue.

In the site console, I've paused the script on the if statement in the short script below

```
    jQuery(function($) { 
        $(".wmc-products").children("li").each(function(i) {
            if (!$(this).children().hasClass("wmc-remove")) {
                $this.hide();
            }
        })
    })
```

Looking at the output of in the console

```
$(this).children()
```

I get

```
s.fn.init(3) [div.wmc-remove, div.wmc-image, div.wmc-details, prevObject: s.fn.init(1)]
0: div.wmc-remove
1: div.wmc-image
2: div.wmc-details
length: 3
prevObject: s.fn.init [li]
__proto__: Object(0)
```

One of the children does have the class wmc-remove. I can't understand why, when I run

```
if (!$(this).children().hasClass("wmc-remove")) { 
        console.log("yay") } else { console.log("nay") 
      };
```

the output is 'nay', and why if I copy the chunk of html from my page and run it in jsfiddle the output changes to 'yay'

Comment: Your code says *"if not has class"* `if (!$(this)....` so when one *does* have the class the output *should be* "nay"

Comment: Perhaps you could include a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`) with some html?

Comment: Do you have some html code

Comment: <Your code says "if not has class" if (!$(this).... so when one does have the class the output should be "nay" >
You are correct - I was using the console code log yay or nay instead of the $this.hide() in my actual code which I can't test because the html is not rendered when I pause the script at this point. If I allow the code to complete, neither the items with children having "wmc-remove" class or those without are hidden.